# Oracle Distinct on one column

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have the table structure in following way:

```
ITEM  LOC  STATUS  QTY
001   RS1    A     10
001   JS1    I     20
110   RS1    A     4
```

I want to retrieve the results based on distinct ITEM only, regardless of that the values come with that

So result should be

```
ITEM   LOC   STATUS   QTY
001    JS1     A      10
110    RS1     A       4
```

How to do that ?

Comment: group by item and use max or min for the other columns

Comment: How to pick the LOC, STATUS and QTY values? All from same row (which), or other strategy?

Answer (score 7):

This is a special case of the [Top N per category problem in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/), where `N = 1`, in case of which some simpler solutions may apply:

#### A standard SQL solution

The existing answers suggest using `row_number()` in a derived table, which obviously works. But [as I have explained in this article](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/09/using-distinct-on-in-non-postgresql-databases/), using `first_value()` would be more straightforward in most cases. Your result could be produced by this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  item,
  first_value (loc)    OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY qty) loc,
  first_value (status) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY qty) status,
  first_value (qty)    OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY qty) qty,
FROM t
ORDER BY item
```

This is assuming you want ordering by `QTY`. Replace the `ORDER BY` clause if some other ordering is desired.

This approach works on all RDBMS

#### An Oracle specific solution

In Oracle, you can use the vendor specific [`FIRST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238) aggregate function, which uses the following syntax

```
SELECT
  item,
  MAX (loc)    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY qty) loc,
  MAX (status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY qty) status,
  MAX (qty)    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY qty) qty,
FROM t
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY item
```

I've seen this perform better than the window function based approach, but do check on your side.

Answer (score 4):

One method is aggregation, if the values don't need to come from the same row:

```
select item, max(loc) as loc, . . .
from t
group by item;
```

If you want all the values from the same row, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by item order by item) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the minimum value per `item` for each column (which is what your expected results show) then:

```
SELECT ITEM,
       MIN( LOC ) AS LOC,
       MIN( status ) AS status,
       MIN( qty ) AS qty
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY item
```

If you want the value for an item that are minimum against a particular order then:

```
SELECT ITEM,
       MIN( LOC )    KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY your_criteria ) AS LOC,
       MIN( status ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY your_criteria ) AS status,
       MIN( qty )    KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY your_criteria ) AS qty
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY item
```

Or if you want to to be all from the same row then:

```
SELECT item, loc, status, qty
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY item ORDER BY your_criteria ) AS RN
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  RN = 1;
```